# Limiting iOS app update to stores in specific countries

Tags: ios, itunes, applications, ios-appstore, itunes-store

We have an iOS app that is available worldwide. If we limit it to UK App Store only, and send a new update of the app on the App Store, will existing users in other countries get the update too? Or will they continue to see the older version of the app?

Comment: non-UK users should not see the new update. They will continue with the old version.

Comment: @BillSmith: are you sure about this? Do you have such experience? I have found mixed views about this. Some say that all would get an update and some say that only users in the selected country will get the update?

Comment: I've done similar shenanigans with the France vs US App Store, but not the UK explicitly. Ultimately, you need to either ask on the developer forum or give it a shot. I can't guarantee the behavior or that it hasn't changed since my experience or that the rules aren't different with the UK store. I suggest you post your question at https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/distribution/app-store